# How to set Connection Timeout for SCOM SDK

Tags: c#, .net, scom, system-center

I have next code:

```
private ManagementGroup ConnectToManagementGroup(string serverName, string domain, string userName, string password)
{
    var settings = new ManagementGroupConnectionSettings(serverName)
    {
        UserName = userName,
        Domain = domain,
        Password = password.ToSecureString()
    };

    var managementGroup = ManagementGroup.Connect(settings);

    if (!managementGroup.IsConnected)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Can't connect to {serverName} SDK service.");
    }

    return managementGroup;
}
```

The code works fine.

But if my SCOM server is down then connection takes one minute before throwing a `TimeOut` exception.

I have found two properties `InactivityTimeout` and `SendReceiveTimeout` in `ManagementGroupConnectionSettings` class.

I have tried to use these properties to change default `TimeOut` value.

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Also I can't find any documentations about connection `TimeOut` for SCOM SDK.

I have reviewed many links: [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/35d1fc3d-9780-4622-8a4b-15ee65503ab7/scom-web-console-time-out?forum=operationsmanagergeneral), [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29347.scom-2012-web-console-timeout-issue.aspx) and [here](http://microsoft.public.opsmgr.general.narkive.com/LOJseHYe/changing-scom-console-timeout)...

But there was no answer for my issue...

**How can I set TimeOut for connection myself?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it's not possible to set the connect timeout.

Long answer. Microsoft uses `DuplexChannelFactory` class for SDK Data Layer connection. This class has 7 different timeout settings: [Explaination of different timeout types](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/explaination-of-different-timeout-types?forum=wcf). The actual code, Microsoft creates an instance of Channel Factory class is below:

```
DuplexChannelFactory<T> duplexChannelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<T>((object) this.clientCallback, (Binding) new IndigoCustomBinding(false, this.connectionSettings.SendReceiveTimeout, this.connectionSettings.InactivityTimeout), new EndpointAddress(new Uri(string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, endpointUri, new object[1]
  {
    (object) this.connectionSettings.ServerName
  })), EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity(string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, spn, new object[1]
  {
    (object) this.connectionSettings.ServerName
  })), new AddressHeaderCollection()));
```

They use custom binding object `internal class IndigoCustomBinding : Binding`, which doesn't override/define `OpenTimeout` property, so this timeout value is left defaulted from the original `Binding` class.

Comment: Thanks for your help again!